# Unable to Retrieve Resource IDs from AccessibilityNodeInfo in Android AccessibilityService

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility

'm developing an Android app where I'm utilizing the AccessibilityService to capture events and retrieve resource IDs from the accessibility nodes. My goal is to collect a list of resource IDs of all visible elements in the active window. However, I'm facing an issue where I'm unable to retrieve the resource IDs as expected.

Here's a simplified version of my MyAccessibilityService class:

```
import androidx.core.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat

class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {

    // Other methods and properties...

    fun getAllVisibleResourceIds(): List<String> {
        val rootInActiveWindow = rootInActiveWindow ?: return emptyList()
        val resourceIds = mutableListOf<String>()

        fun recurseTree(node: AccessibilityNodeInfo) {
            val resourceId = node.viewIdResourceName
            if (!resourceId.isNullOrBlank()) {
                resourceIds.add(resourceId)
            }

            for (i in 0 until node.childCount) {
                val child = node.getChild(i)
                if(child != null) {
                    recurseTree(child)
                }
            }
        }

        recurseTree(rootInActiveWindow)
        return resourceIds
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<accessibility-service
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
android:notificationTimeout="100"
android:canControlMagnification="true"
android:canPerformGestures="true"

android:canRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility="true"
android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
    android:packageNames="com.eric.gdbutton2"
android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description" />
```

Despite my efforts, the getAllVisibleResourceIds() function isn't returning any resource IDs. I've made sure the service is enabled in the device settings, and I'm capturing the right accessibility events. What could be causing this issue? Are there any steps I might be missing or mistakes in my implementation?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

getAllVisibleResourceIds()